# Fuzzy Lookup add on in Excel not matching results as expected

Tags: excel, fuzzy-search

I have various addresses I'm matching with fuzzy lookup in excel.

To the eye some seem pretty similar but fuzzy lookup is returning a 0 similarity score. I've removed all spaces (including trailing) so this shouldn't impact it.

An example is this:

Address 1: 700AndersonHillRdPurchase10577-1444

Address 2: 700AndersonHillRoadPurchase10577-1401

I've set the threshold to 0.

Is it a bug?

Comment: What, exactly, is it that you are trying?

Comment: As per the post I'm matching two text fields  using the fuzzy lookup add on in excel.